# BizTalk - polling an Oracle database package

Tags: oracle, package, integration, biztalk, polling

I need to poll an Oracle database in BizTalk. In the postPollStatement I need to add the package that has been created for me in the Oracle DB. Can anyone assist me with this?

I have created the schema in Visual Studio, the port is created and I have configured everything except the postPollStatement.

**EDIT1:**
I have done some research and followed Microsoft Docs but still not managed to get the postPollStatement working.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-oracle-database/poll-oracle-db-using-stored-procedures-functions-or-packaged-procedures

**This is the error I receive**: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Comment: Doesn't using the Add, Add Generated Item, Consume Adapter Service create an binding file for you that contains that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working you need to do the following:

**polledDataAvailableStatement**: SQL Statement that returns '1' or '0'.
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE

**pollingAction**: Retrieve the polling action from the schema generated for the inbound message.

**pollingStatement:** For this binding property, specify the entire XML request message that you generate from the schema in Visual Studio.
(No parameter needed if not specified in schema).